# Xamarin.Forms FormsGallery MasterDetailDemoPage handle click event on generated page

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying  to learn Xamarin.Forms, and while there are a lot of samples available, not many are commented. 
I would like to use either the FormsGallery MasterDetailDemoPage (found here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/MasterDetailPageDemoPage.cs) or the CarouselPage (found here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/CarouselPageDemoPage.cs) but i need to be able to handle click events on the pages that are generated.

The NamedColorPage (found here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/NamedColorPage.cs)n is used in both of those examples.

I have no problem generating the pages but how do I handle click events on the generated pages.

For example, if the NamedColor object had another property called Descriptions that was List, and I want to click a button on the NamedColorPage that takes me to another page that shows the description/s how would I do that?

```
Button colourDescription = new Button
{
     Text = "Description
};

colourDescription.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{

    //open page showing description here

}
```

I presume it is something to do with SetBinding or BindingContext, but there is very limited  documentation on any of this, and none aimed at a complete newbie.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out

```
Color col = (Color)BindingContext;
```

then

```
List<string> descr = col.Description;
```